# Combine two columns together from separate tables

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1062

*Let's say for instance:*

- I have two tables: **old_data** and **new_data**.
- Both **old_data** and **new_data** have one column called **this_is_col**.
- Both **old_data** and **new_data** have various (hundreds) of rows of dates (2010-02-06, 2010-01-09, 2007-06-02, etc.).  Both tables don't necessarily have the same dates, but they both have the same format.
- The fields of both tables are various integers.

---

*My task:*

- Copy the fields from **old_data** to **new_data**.
- If a date exists in both tables, the field in **new_data** will be replaced.
- If the date doesn't exist in **new_data**, then the correct row will be added and the field will be copied over.

---

*Here is how far I've gotten:*

Create a temporary column:

```
ALTER TABLE `new_data` ADD `tempColumn` TEXT NULL;
```

Copy over data from **old_data**:

```
INSERT INTO `new_data` (`tempColumn`) SELECT `this_is_col` FROM `old_data`;
```

Combine temporary column and **new_data** . **this_is_col**. (I haven't really figured this step out since I haven't gotten this far).

```
MERGE? `tempColumn` `this_is_col`;
```

Delete temporary table

```
ALTER TABLE `new_data` DROP `tempColumn`;
```

---

Upon performing the second action (transferring the data over to the temporary column) I get this error:

`#1062 - Duplicate entry '0000-00-00' for key 1`

And now I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated. I'm using MySQL and phpMyAdmin to test the SQL commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your dates are indexed as unique keys:

```
INSERT INTO newtable
SELECT *
FROM oldtable
ON DUPLICATE KEY column1=oldcolumn1, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you want [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). your solution already satisfies steps 1 and 3 of your task, ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE will take care of step 2.

Answer (score 0):

How about just doing an `UPDATE` and `INSERT`?

```
UPDATE new_data SET col=col 
FROM new_data a join old_data b on a.this_is_col = b.this_is_col
```

Then

```
INSERT INTO new_data (cols) SELECT cols 
FROM old_data WHERE this_is_col NOT IN (SELECT this_is_col FROM new_data)
```

Unless I misunderstood...

Answer (score 0):

If you'd rather delete the row first, instead of updating:  [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)

It'd be just one line too, so:  REPLACE data SELECT, you wouldn't have to do the weirdness with adding a text column.